# Why do obj. files contain normals

Tags: object

Simple question, why do object files contain normals, you can just calculate the normals right?

If I'm correct I'd just have to take the crossproduct between the vector point1-point2 and point1-point3, so which would save me the time of reading them from a file.

EDIT:

Trying to be more specific, this is a file I've found and which I want to use:

```
g cube

v  0.0  0.0  0.0
v  0.0  0.0  1.0
v  0.0  1.0  0.0
v  0.0  1.0  1.0
v  1.0  0.0  0.0
v  1.0  0.0  1.0
v  1.0  1.0  0.0
v  1.0  1.0  1.0

vn  0.0  0.0  1.0
vn  0.0  0.0 -1.0
vn  0.0  1.0  0.0
vn  0.0 -1.0  0.0
vn  1.0  0.0  0.0
vn -1.0  0.0  0.0

f  1//2  7//2  5//2
f  1//2  3//2  7//2 
f  1//6  4//6  3//6 
f  1//6  2//6  4//6 
f  3//3  8//3  7//3 
f  3//3  4//3  8//3 
f  5//5  7//5  8//5 
f  5//5  8//5  6//5 
f  1//4  5//4  6//4 
f  1//4  6//4  2//4 
f  2//1  6//1  8//1 
f  2//1  8//1  4//1
```

EDIT 2:

Because people complained:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file

Comment: What do you mean by "object files"? It's a very generic description, you'll have to provide a bit more context.

Comment: for example cube.obj; containing vertices, normals en faces of the model I'm trying to render.

Comment: Context, not a description. I can guess that you mean "files containing some description of an object". What's missing is what technology you're using, what *specific* file format you mean, etc.

Comment: There are thousands of things called "object files".  You're not giving us any clue about your particular meaning of "object file".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can calculate normals, but it takes time to compute them. When you have a lot of meshes and have to render at 60 fps (or more), its more performant to load precomputed normals into the GPU. also crossproduct between the vector point1-point2 and point1-point3, just gives the face normal. to get the per vertex normals that are required for Goraud shading, you have to average the face normals at every vertex. so you can see the computation gets deeper.

Comment: I see, so it's really just for performance and nothing else, that'd make sense.

Comment: But if you rotate a model, the normals would change aswell, right? So you'd have to recaculate them anyway?

Comment: No, the normals (expressed in the model's reference frame) don't change when you rotate the model. It is the view matrix that changes.

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense, thank you :)

Comment: i am giving the question a +1 to offset the downvote given by someone. i don't think it is an unreasonable question. good luck!